# How do I covert my 2 backup mage1.img and image0.img fils into 1 .iso file to reinstall

Tags: server, backup

I have backed up Linux however my VM backup results in 2 image  files. image1.img and image0.img.  I am stumped and would Like to have some suggestions on how I can use the image files to recreate a new bootable Ubuntu server install .iso.  I basically want to clone my entire ubuntu server configuration that I have established.

Answer (score 0):

To combine 2 or more files it is easy to use cat as this:

```
cat image1.img image2.img > result.img
```

But to make a bootable .iso image tasks is more complicated, xorriso is a nice tool, please refer to https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/
xorriso part.

In addition if you made .img file using dd you can restore back your OS using a live image running a command like this:

```
dd if=/path/to/image1.img of=/dev/sdxx bs=64M
```

Comment: Presumably, these are not text files...but binary images.  You can concatenate them but I'm not sure if there's a meaning to that...  For example, you cannot merge two Word files using `cat`...

Comment: As you know .img files are like disk partitions, so concatenating  them will produce a disk with 2 or more partitions.
look at https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/
Author uses .img files as partitions and write them to .iso file.